# Scrapy General Scraper

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

I've tried to constuct a general scraper for scrapy - although it seems a bit buggy. The idea is that it should take the URL as an input and only scrape pages from that specific URL, but it appears to be going off the site to youtube etc. Ideally, it would also have an option for depth, which allows 1,2,3, etc. as the number of links deep to go away from the initial page. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib
from route import urls
import pickle
import os
import urllib2
import urlparse

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

def getAllUrl(url):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen( url ).read()
    except:
        return []
    urlList = []
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        soup.prettify()
        for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            if not 'http://' in anchor['href']:
                if urlparse.urljoin(url, anchor['href']) not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(urlparse.urljoin(url, anchor['href']))
            else:
                if anchor['href'] not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(anchor['href'])

        length = len(urlList)

        return urlList
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e

def listAllUrl(url):
    urls_new = list(set(url))
    return urls_new
count = 0

main_url = str(raw_input('Enter the url : '))
url_split=main_url.split('.',1)
folder_name =url_split[1]
txtfile_split = folder_name.split('.',1)
txtfile_name = txtfile_split[0]
url = getAllUrl(main_url)
urls_new = listAllUrl(url)

os.makedirs('c:/Scrapy/Extracted/'+folder_name+"/")
for url in urls_new:
    if url.startswith("http") or url.startswith(" "):
        if(main_url == url):
            url = url
        else:
            pass
    else:
        url = main_url+url
    if '#' in url:
        new_url = str(url).replace('#','/')
    else:
        new_url =url
    count = count+1
    if new_url:
        print""+str(count)+">>",new_url
        html = urllib.urlopen(new_url).read()
        page_text_data=text_from_html(html)
        with open("c:/Scrapy/Extracted/"+folder_name+"/"+txtfile_name+".txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.writelines("\n\n"+new_url.encode('utf-8')+"\n\n"+page_text_data.encode('utf-8'))
            path ='c:/Scrapy/Extracted/'+folder_name+"/"
        filename ="url"+str(count)+".txt"
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as temp_file:
            temp_file.write(page_text_data.encode('utf-8'))
            temp_file.close()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution doesn't involve Scrapy at all. But as you asked specifically for Scrapy, here you go.

Base your spider on [`CrawlSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) class. This allows you to crawl given website and possibly specify rules that navigation should obey.

To forbid off-site requests, either use `allowed_domains` spider attribute. Alternatively, if you use `CrawlSpider` class, you can specificy `allow_domains` (or the other way around, `deny_domains`) attribute of [`LinkExtractor`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors) constructor in `Rule`.

To limit the depth crawl goes into, use [`DEPTH_LIMIT`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit) in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a tag scrapy but you don't use it at all. I recommend you try to use it - it's really easy. Much easier than try to develop in yourself. There's already an option to limit requests by specific domains.